# PHP Global vs Javascript Global

Tags: php, joomla, global-variables

When I was learning javascript, the global variable issue was emphasized by book or tech article authors, a.k.a one should always try to avoid using global variables. One of the reasons I believe is to avoid naming conflict. And I think no matter what language we are using, naming conflict will always be an issue.

However, when I read PHP books, using of global variable is not perticularly mentioned or marked as bad practice. So shall I pay attention to it?

For example, I am trying to modify some PHP file in Joomla. if I write a custom function `getJson()` in a template file of a module, how do I know the function name is not being used somewhere by other components?

Comment: PHP recommends namespacing to avoid such situations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question is about a variables the second about function names.

Is using of global variables bad pratice?

Yes, if you are using too many variables and lose the overview about the useage! 
Think about a coder team with 20 coder on one big project with 1000+ files.

No, if you use globals wisly.
Like the most Framework do.

Topic: TO OOP OR NOT TO OOP (Object-oriented programming)

> So shall I pay attention to it?

In your case, using Joomla, you should take a look how and for what Joomla is using global vars. And use them in that way too.

In your other projects, give them an custom useage,like: global vars only for class instances.

Its all about how you code, more OOP or more PROCEDUAL or all mixed up .... 
php is a big open world.

> how do I know the function name is not being used somewhere by other
>   components?
>   function_exists('getJson');  ;)

Whatever, for this problem php has namespaces.

```
namespace MySpace {
 function getJson(){}
}
use MySpace\getJson as getJson;

getJson($args);
```

You should read a little about it.

> if I write a custom function getJson() in a template file

You can do with a anonymous function:

```
$getJson = function(){};
```

instead of creating a global function.
If the function is only used in this template!

Hope that helps a little.

Comment: Thanks, I think ultimately namespace is the way. But I've come across lots of joomla components/module/plugins, none of them PHP files uses namespace, which makes me uncertain about whetherf I should use namespace at all.

Comment: $getJson = function(){};  $getJson($args); i have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. Now I figure out my question is actually about joomla namespacing rule, a.k.a whether components/modules have their own namespace after registered with joomla core. Starting a post in stackexchange joomla now.

Answer (score 0):

Investigation is key in your situation.

1. Make sure `error_reporting(E_ALL);` is set in your development environment.
2. Before creating the function, run a recursive search through all of your PHP files for some combination of `function getJson(`

I am not familiar with Joomla but if [namespacing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) is being used then you may run into false-positives.

3. If namespacing is being used then make sure to not run into namespacing conflicts by referring to first point - `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
4. Use namespaces like a boss (requires PHP 5.3.0 or later):

```
namespace NameSpaceThatIsDefinitelyNotUsedanywhereksdgbdihjfgbdfbgd{
    function getJson(){}
}
use NameSpaceThatIsDefinitelyNotUsedanywhereksdgbdihjfgbdfbgd\getJson as getJson;

getJson($args);
```

**Instructions for #2**

1. Choose your directory
2. Limit your search to PHP files only
3. Tell it you want to search for `function getJson(`
4. Click "Find All"

[image]

Comment: Joomla website can contain scores of extensions and the thousnads of php files, if everytime I try to write a new function I need to search it will be not so practical. Is there any 'smarter' way for this?

Comment: I see. I will show you a neat trick in Notepad++ which will save you lots of time.

Comment: Please be noted my website is live, I am just making a tiny modification so I don't have a current version of my website on my local machine.

Comment: @shenkwen You will need to get a current version onto your local machine. Please see the update.

Comment: I think you were gonna suggest me use search all files in notepad++, I used it before and it took about 3-4 minutes to conduct a thorough search against joomla system...

Comment: @shenkwen how often do you plan on doing this?

Comment: @shenkwen Not sure what else to tell you besides I'll perform the search for you at a modest charge of $2/min. You should really consider why you need to put that function in a template. It sounds like it should be put somewhere else especially if you are using a framework like Joomla. Where do the docs tell you to put it?

Comment: Thanks maybe I should search joomla + custom function